# Scipy Linear Programming returns False for success

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I am working on a project about Transportation Network Analysis. My network contains data such as nodes, edges, free-flow travel times, capacity, etc. I need to find the volume of edges (links) by using the Frank-Wolf algorithm. I used scipy.optimize.linprog in my code; however, it returns False for success.

The first code is:

```
result = optimize.linprog(c_0, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)  # min(c_0*x) such that: Ax=b
print(result)
result = np.reshape(result['x'], (k, n))
xa = np.sum(result, axis=0)  # initial value of xa
print(xa)
```

The output of the first code is:

```
     con: array([ 1.17458269e+04,  1.19588056e+03, -5.99940081e+00,  1.19488066e+03,
        1.19388076e+03, -5.99940073e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920106e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00,  9.71902933e+02,  9.95900537e+02, -5.99940081e+00,
        1.13188696e+03,  8.89911122e+02,  8.51914917e+02, -5.99940084e+00,
       -5.99940084e+00, -3.99960052e+00,  8.13918712e+02,  5.33946673e+02,
        5.33946673e+02,  6.91930895e+02, -7.99920110e+00,  6.63933691e+02,
        1.19688046e+03,  1.15548460e+04, -5.99940084e+00,  1.13488666e+03,
        1.17388276e+03, -5.99940081e+00, -5.99940078e+00, -7.99920111e+00,
       -5.99940078e+00,  9.91900936e+02,  1.01589854e+03, -5.99940087e+00,
        8.11918912e+02,  8.49915117e+02,  8.41915916e+02, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  1.17388276e+03,  5.33946673e+02,
        6.13938684e+02,  6.01939883e+02, -7.99920113e+00,  5.33946673e+02,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
        1.19688046e+03,  1.13588656e+03, -5.99940075e+00,  1.10638950e+04,
        1.19388076e+03, -5.99940078e+00, -5.99940081e+00, -7.99920113e+00,
       -5.99940081e+00,  9.71902933e+02,  9.65903533e+02, -5.99940081e+00,
        8.51914917e+02,  8.09919111e+02,  7.51924903e+02, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940085e+00, -3.99960056e+00,  7.23927699e+02,  5.53944676e+02,
        5.73942679e+02,  5.31946873e+02, -7.99920109e+00,  7.23927699e+02,
        1.19688046e+03,  1.17588256e+03, -5.99940085e+00,  1.19488066e+03,
        1.13728642e+04, -5.99940079e+00, -5.99940091e+00, -7.99920121e+00,
       -5.99940080e+00,  1.02189794e+03,  8.75912520e+02, -5.99940083e+00,
        8.21917913e+02,  7.89921108e+02,  7.31926900e+02, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940079e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  6.53934690e+02,  7.23927699e+02,
        7.33926701e+02,  8.41915916e+02, -7.99920111e+00,  5.33946673e+02,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
        9.76902434e+02,  9.95900537e+02, -5.99940080e+00,  9.74902634e+02,
        1.02389774e+03, -5.99940083e+00, -5.99940084e+00, -7.99920109e+00,
       -5.99940077e+00,  1.22707745e+04,  1.20587957e+03, -5.99940074e+00,
        8.11918912e+02,  8.89911122e+02,  1.19188096e+03, -5.99940081e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960054e+00,  1.05389474e+03,  8.53914717e+02,
        8.13918712e+02,  8.71912920e+02, -7.99920105e+00,  5.33946673e+02,
        9.96900437e+02,  1.01589854e+03, -5.99940085e+00,  9.64903632e+02,
        8.73912720e+02, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940080e+00, -7.99920109e+00,
       -5.99940080e+00,  1.20187996e+03,  1.21647851e+04, -5.99940083e+00,
        8.41915916e+02,  1.18988116e+03,  1.00189994e+03, -5.99940083e+00,
       -5.99940081e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  8.53914717e+02,  6.63933691e+02,
        5.43945675e+02,  9.91900936e+02, -7.99920107e+00,  9.43905730e+02,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
        1.13688646e+03,  8.15918512e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  8.54914617e+02,
        8.23917713e+02, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00,  8.11918911e+02,  8.45915516e+02, -5.99940086e+00,
        1.04109602e+04,  7.79922107e+02,  7.71922906e+02, -5.99940081e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  6.13938684e+02,  5.33946673e+02,
        5.53944676e+02,  6.01939883e+02, -7.99920111e+00,  1.19388076e+03,
        8.96910423e+02,  8.55914517e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  8.14918612e+02,
        7.93920709e+02, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940083e+00, -7.99920109e+00,
       -5.99940083e+00,  8.91910922e+02,  1.19588056e+03, -5.99940083e+00,
        7.81921907e+02,  1.19888026e+04,  1.19188096e+03, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940083e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  1.02389774e+03,  8.53914717e+02,
        7.83921708e+02,  8.11918911e+02, -7.99920111e+00,  1.02389774e+03,
        8.56914418e+02,  8.45915516e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  7.54924604e+02,
        7.33926701e+02, -5.99940083e+00, -5.99940083e+00, -7.99920112e+00,
       -5.99940083e+00,  1.19188096e+03,  1.00589954e+03, -5.99940083e+00,
        7.71922906e+02,  1.18988116e+03,  1.28107206e+04, -5.99940081e+00,
       -5.99940085e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  1.19388076e+03,  1.14388576e+03,
        1.03389674e+03,  1.19188096e+03, -7.99920110e+00,  8.23917713e+02,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
        8.16918412e+02,  1.17588256e+03, -5.99940082e+00,  7.24927600e+02,
        6.53934690e+02, -5.99940085e+00, -5.99940081e+00, -7.99920107e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00,  1.05189494e+03,  8.55914517e+02, -5.99940083e+00,
        6.11938884e+02,  1.01989814e+03,  1.19188096e+03, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940079e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  1.20927923e+04,  1.19388076e+03,
        1.00389974e+03,  9.91900936e+02, -7.99920108e+00,  7.23927699e+02,
        5.36946374e+02,  5.35946474e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  5.54944576e+02,
        7.23927699e+02, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940081e+00, -7.99920109e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00,  8.51914917e+02,  6.65933491e+02, -5.99940082e+00,
        5.31946873e+02,  8.49915117e+02,  1.14188596e+03, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940080e+00, -3.99960056e+00,  1.19388076e+03,  1.05929421e+04,
        1.19388076e+03,  1.19188096e+03, -7.99920110e+00,  5.43945675e+02,
        5.36946374e+02,  6.15938485e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  5.74942579e+02,
        7.33926701e+02, -5.99940084e+00, -5.99940083e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00,  8.11918911e+02,  5.45945475e+02, -5.99940081e+00,
        5.51944876e+02,  7.79922107e+02,  1.03189694e+03, -5.99940080e+00,
       -5.99940081e+00, -3.99960056e+00,  1.00389974e+03,  1.19388076e+03,
        1.08429171e+04,  1.19188096e+03, -7.99920113e+00,  1.19388076e+03,
        6.96930396e+02,  6.05939483e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  5.34946573e+02,
        8.43915716e+02, -5.99940083e+00, -5.99940083e+00, -7.99920109e+00,
       -5.99940083e+00,  8.71912920e+02,  9.95900537e+02, -5.99940083e+00,
        6.01939883e+02,  8.09919111e+02,  1.19188096e+03, -5.99940081e+00,
       -5.99940078e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  9.93900736e+02,  1.19388076e+03,
        1.19388076e+03,  1.16308384e+04, -7.99920112e+00,  1.02389774e+03,
       -2.99970041e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -4.99950069e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -7.99920110e+00, -9.99900137e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -3.99960055e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -7.99920110e+00, -5.99940082e+00,
        6.66933392e+02,  5.35946474e+02, -5.99940082e+00,  7.24927600e+02,
        5.33946673e+02, -5.99940081e+00, -5.99940082e+00, -7.99920110e+00,
       -5.99940082e+00,  5.31946873e+02,  9.45905530e+02, -5.99940082e+00,
        1.19188096e+03,  1.01989814e+03,  8.21917913e+02, -5.99940082e+00,
       -5.99940086e+00, -3.99960055e+00,  7.23927699e+02,  5.43945675e+02,
        1.19388076e+03,  1.02189794e+03, -7.99920107e+00,  1.05329480e+04])
     fun: 4381.002675394279
 message: 'The algorithm terminated successfully and determined that the problem is infeasible.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([], dtype=float64)
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: array([1.33630125, 1.33630125, 0.72363567, ..., 1.25494354, 1.2520338 ,
       1.01759439])
[25.2836661  25.2836661  23.87454089 23.85736666 22.92358045 25.21218089
 23.77225208 23.82974501 25.39313184 23.82974501 24.83242583 24.49277083
 25.37410372 22.90803073 23.68565375 24.81485143 22.88570538 24.25372542
 24.45895798 24.68762057 22.92335758 23.92017804 24.27533126 23.11925871
 24.58518598 25.23224542 24.60817148 23.14973545 24.26067157 24.60817148
 24.59406271 24.6106668  23.6338265  23.75661862 24.24302036 24.72759441
 24.39088079 23.6338265  24.60238281 24.71703015 23.86485208 24.78126498
 23.29432843 23.86485208 24.04833536 25.12592644 24.26371588 23.24762732
 24.39088079 24.33909973 23.87288055 24.01656751 24.04795658 23.70134198
 24.30170872 24.30170872 24.23917449 24.64327592 24.07970166 24.34396678
 24.67725583 25.12592644 24.32280263 23.60364009 24.23113127 24.21024173
 24.40209124 24.3105531  23.75661862 23.63524614 24.42120405 24.17605304
 24.42120405 24.36787799 24.23917449]
```

The second code (added method:'simplex') is:

```
result = optimize.linprog(c_0, A_eq=A, b_eq=b, method='simplex')  # min(c_0*x) such that: Ax=b
print(result)
result = np.reshape(result['x'], (k, n))
xa = np.sum(result, axis=0)  # initial value of xa
print(xa)
```

The output of the second code is:

```
     con: array([9.350e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.200e+03, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.000e+01, 0.000e+00,
       2.400e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 1.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 1.036e+04, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 4.000e+01, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.000e+01, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       1.000e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 4.200e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 9.810e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       3.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 2.000e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.020e+04, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.200e+02, 2.400e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 2.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 5.000e+01, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.025e+04, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 5.200e+02, 5.400e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 2.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 9.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.096e+04, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.300e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.900e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 3.000e+01, 0.000e+00,
       9.630e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 1.500e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 5.800e+02,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.000e+01, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 3.000e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 1.001e+04, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 4.000e+01, 7.900e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 9.970e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 7.800e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 3.600e+02, 0.000e+00, 7.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       1.017e+04, 0.000e+00, 4.200e+02, 1.000e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.700e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 8.750e+03, 5.600e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 8.000e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.600e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.031e+04, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.900e+02,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 4.000e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.200e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.100e+02, 1.041e+04, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       6.700e+02, 5.400e+02, 0.000e+00, 7.300e+02, 5.400e+02, 0.000e+00,
       0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 5.400e+02, 9.500e+02, 0.000e+00,
       1.200e+03, 1.030e+03, 8.300e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
       7.300e+02, 5.500e+02, 1.200e+03, 1.030e+03, 0.000e+00, 1.054e+04])
     fun: 202134.0
 message: "Phase 1 of the simplex method failed to find a feasible solution. The pseudo-objective function evaluates to 1.6e+05 which exceeds the required tolerance of 1e-09 for a solution to be considered 'close enough' to zero to be a basic solution. Consider increasing the tolerance to be greater than 1.6e+05. If this tolerance is unacceptably  large the problem may be infeasible."
     nit: 1000
   slack: array([], dtype=float64)
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: array([1200.,    0.,    0., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.])
[11740.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  1740.  9690.     0.     0.
     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0. 11940.     0.  1830.     0.
     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  7910.     0.     0.     0.     0.
  5050.     0.     0.     0.     0.  7570.  2220.     0.     0.     0.
     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.  9650.  3550.     0.  7170.
     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   120.     0.     0.     0.
     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
```

I would appreciate any help in solving this problem.

Comment: In the first code (with default solver, interior point method) the message says that the problem is infeasible. Regarding the second code, if the user doesn't provide an initial feasible solution then the phase I of the simplex method is to find an initial feasible solution. Probably the problem is related with the constraints of the problem.

Comment: @jomavera Thank you for your suggestion. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the **incidence matrix** that caused the problem.

I should use this code:

```
incMatrixScipy = nx.incidence_matrix(Graph1, oriented=True)
incMatrixNumPy = incMatrixScipy.todense()
```

Instead of this code:

```
incMatrixScipy = nx.incidence_matrix(Graph1)
incMatrixNumPy = incMatrixScipy.todense()
```

I need to add **oriented=True** to receive the correct incidence matrix because my graph is directed.